# How to use js-datepicker in multiple elements using class

Tags: javascript

I'm using [js-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker) for datepicker on my project. I chose this library because I wanted to use vanilla JS on my application so I won't be using JQuery UI datepickers nor HTML5 input date(for browser compatibility).

The problem is I have multiple inputs that will be datepicker but when I create an instance using their classes the datepicker is only binded on the first element with that class

HTML inputs

```
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp1">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp2">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp3">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp4">
```

JS instantiation

```
const test_dp = datepicker('.test-datepickers', {
        formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
            const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
            date  = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset*60*1000));
            input.value = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        },
        showAllDates: true,
        minDate: new Date()
    });
```

Please do not suggest to create an instance by id cause I'm creating these inputs dynamically (when the a button is pressed).

Comment: Do a forEach loop on elements with class `test-datepickers` and pass the event.target to datepicker instead of the class name

Comment: @MajiD `event.target` in a `.forEach()`?

Comment: oh sorry i mean every element of the forEach loop

Comment: The library you're using can [only handle one element](https://github.com/qodesmith/datepicker/blob/master/src/datepicker.js#L148). So you will have to built that function on your own as MajiD already suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for all the elements with the given class and then loop over them to add the datepicker.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".test-datepickers");

for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
  const node = items[i];
  
  datepicker(node, {
    formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
      const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
      date = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset * 60 * 1000));
      input.value = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    },
    showAllDates: true,
    minDate: new Date()
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-datepicker/dist/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/js-datepicker/dist/datepicker.min.css">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp1">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp2">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp3">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp4">
```

For dynamic usage,

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".test-datepickers");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  let inp = document.createElement("input")
  inp.setAttribute("type","text");
  document.body.appendChild(inp);
  
   datepicker(inp, {
    formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
      const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
      date = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset * 60 * 1000));
      input.value = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    },
    showAllDates: true,
    minDate: new Date()
  });
})

for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
  const node = items[i];
  
  datepicker(node, {
    formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
      const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
      date = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset * 60 * 1000));
      input.value = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    },
    showAllDates: true,
    minDate: new Date()
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-datepicker/dist/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/js-datepicker/dist/datepicker.min.css">
<button>Add date</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp1">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp2">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp3">
<input type="text" class="form-control test-datepickers" id="dp4">
```

Comment: kinda weird but do you know why I'm getting this error `document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function` ?

Comment: Some browsers may not support forEach on node list @DarthVader I've edited the answer to use a normal for loop

Comment: Okay now the datepicker is showing. However when I select a date it still not display it's value on the input text not like in your snippets :/. I'm creating each input text when a button is clicked would that be a factor?

Comment: @DarthVader If you create them dynamically you have to also add the datepicker "dynamically" on the newly created elements.

Comment: Yes, actually what I'm doing is that whenever a new input is created I called the loop you've provided

Comment: @DarthVader For dynamic inputs, you will have to call the datepicker on the newly created input element. I've addaded a new demo

Comment: Still not working but I think your code works perfectly so I'll just work on that. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @DarthVader Don't run the loop whenever an element is added. Call datepicker on only the element that was just added.